# How to resolve 'Attempted Update of read only column' [Sql state:42000 , ISC Error code: 335544359]

Tags: jmeter

When   i   am trying following   Jmeter JDBC   request:

```
Insert into employee(EMP_NO,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,PHONE_EXT,HIRE_DATE,DEPT_NO,JOB_CODE,JOB_GRADE,JOB_COUNTRY,SALARY,FULL_NAME)values('420','SONALI','ARORA','250','1993-09-02 00.00.00.0','600','VP','2','USA','50000.00','ARORASONALI')
```

> Response Error:
>   Attempted update of read only column [Sql state:42000,ISC Error code: 335544359]

DB used: Firebird

Apache JMeter Version: 5.0

Expected:   JDBC   request should add the result in the employee table

Comment: Is there a read-only column in your database?

Answer (score 0):

Please check command insert and try new value insert to DB. I think it's not about permission